# How to replace auth0.com with WebProduct name on the grant access Popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, auth0, google-signin

How to replace auth0.com with WebProduct on the grant access Popup.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, it only shows `auth0.com` there if you are in development and haven't yet set up your own Google OAuth app. You can find some instructions on setting that up here: https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/google

Answer (score 2):

You should use your own keys and a custom domain in order to get rid of the auth0.com part.

Google uses the TLD+1 of the redirect URI received in the request so if using a custom domain that would be your domain.